# How to hide/show text box based on radio button list selected value

Tags: asp.net

How to make when I click on List Item Text="Yes", TextBox1 would be visible and when I click on List Item Text="No", TextBox1 would be hidden?
how I need to do this using java script in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet might might work for you:

```
<script>

function onChange(event){
    if(event.currentTarget.value === "Yes"){
        document.getElementById('TextBox1').style.display = 'inline';
    }
    if(event.currentTarget.value === "No"){
        document.getElementById('TextBox1').style.display = 'none';
    }    
}

document.getElementById('myDropDownId').addEventListener('change', onChange, true);

</script>
```